# Variable transferred from one script to another, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, tic-tac-toe

I want to program a tic tac toe game but came across my first problem:

I would like to transfer the int variable "Level" from this spript:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Box : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int index;
    public Mark mark;
    public bool isMarked;
    public static int Level;

    // [SerializeField] public int Level;

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        index = transform.GetSiblingIndex () ;
        mark = Mark.None;
        isMarked = false;
        Level = 0;
    }

    public void SetAsMarked (Sprite sprite, Mark mark, Color color)
    {
        this.mark = mark;
        Level = Level + 1;
        
        if (Level == 2)
        {
            isMarked = true;
            GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        }

        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;
        spriteRenderer.color = color;
    }
}
```

into this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Input Settings : ")]
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask boxesLayerMask;
    [SerializeField] private float touchRadius;

    [Header("Mark Sprites : ")]
    [SerializeField] private Sprite spriteX;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite spriteO;

    [Header("Mark Colors Level 1: ")]
    [SerializeField] private Color colorX;
    [SerializeField] private Color colorO;

    [Header("Mark Colors Level 2: ")]
    [SerializeField] private Color colorX2;
    [SerializeField] private Color colorO2;

    public Mark[] marks;

    private Camera cam;

    private Mark currentMark;

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;

        currentMark = Mark.X;

        marks = new Mark[9];
    }

    private void Update()
    {   
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {   
             Vector2 touchPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(touchPosition, touchRadius, boxesLayerMask);

            if (hit)//box ist touched
                HitBox(hit.GetComponent<Box>());
        }  
    }
   
    private void HitBox(Box box)
    {
        if(!box.isMarked)
            marks[box.index] = currentMark;

        box.SetAsMarked(GetSprite(), currentMark, GetColor());

        //chek if anybody wins:
        bool won = CheckIfWin();
        if (won)
        {
            Debug.Log(currentMark.ToString() + "Wins.");
        }

        SwitchPlayer();
    }    

    private bool CheckIfWin()
    {
        return
         AreBoxesMatched (0, 1, 2) || AreBoxesMatched (3, 4, 5) ||
         AreBoxesMatched (6, 7, 8) || AreBoxesMatched (0, 3, 6) ||
         AreBoxesMatched (1, 4, 7) || AreBoxesMatched (0, 1, 2) ||
         AreBoxesMatched (0, 4, 8) || AreBoxesMatched (2, 4, 6);
    }

    private bool AreBoxesMatched(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        Mark m = currentMark;
        bool matched = (marks[i] == m && marks[j] == m && marks[k] == m) ;

        return matched;
    }
    
    private void SwitchPlayer ()
    {
        currentMark = (currentMark == Mark.X) ? Mark.O : Mark.X ;
    }

    private Color GetColor()
    {
        if (Level == 1) // <- Here I want to get the variable from the other spript. 
        {
            return (currentMark == Mark.X) ? colorX : colorO;
        }
        else
            return (currentMark == Mark.X) ? colorX2 : colorO2;
    }

    private Sprite GetSprite () 
    {
        return (currentMark == Mark.X) ? spriteX : spriteO;
    }
}
```

, I am sure that it is possible and Have searched on the Internet but have not progressed how exactly I have to do this with this script now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You currently have the Level variable in you Box class set as static, so you should just be able to reference Box.Level to access your Level variable.

That being said, the way you have structured this appears a bit off to me. It seems like a board would have nine Boxes - so you would instantiate your box object nine times and arrange them to make your board. If we follow down that train of thought, it isn't clear what your Level is supposed to represent, but it seems like Level either shouldn't be static or it should be in a different class. If Level is supposed to be different between each box then you should remove the static modifier, otherwise the Level variable would probably make more sense in your Board class or some other more general class. The fact that SetAsMarked() increments level gives me the sense that it shouldn't be static and you should be instantiating multiple boxes. Then - finally coming back to how this answers your question - the box could just get and set its own color when you set it as marked using the level that it stores itself, which would make much more structural sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GetComponent<>()` method. `GetComponent` searches for components attached to a certain game object. In unity, scripts can be components.

Here is an example for getting the variable from a script on the `object1` game object.

First script:

```cs
public GameObject object1;

void Update()
{
    int number = object1.GetComponent<Script2>().num;
    Debug.Log(number);
}
```

Second script called “Script2” that is attached to the `object1` game object:

```cs
public int num = 5;
```

The first script will be printing the number 5. This is because the variable `num` from `Script2` on `object1` is set to 5.

**Important:** You need the variable you are accessing to be public.

---

**Applying this to your situation.**

Now, we will apply this to your situation. We should just do the same thing as before, but with your scripts.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Box : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int index;
    public Mark mark;
    public bool isMarked;
    public int Level;

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {   
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        index = transform.GetSiblingIndex () ;
        mark = Mark.None;
        isMarked = false;
        Level = 0;  
    }
    public void SetAsMarked (Sprite sprite, Mark mark, Color color)
    {
        this.mark = mark;
        Level = Level + 1;
        if (Level == 2)
        {
            isMarked = true;
            GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        }
         spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;
         spriteRenderer.color = color;
    }
}
```

That was your script with a few changes, but this is what I will use (because the rest is not required)

```cs
    ...
    public int Level;
    ...
```

First, get rid of the static in this variable.

Now, we should access this by the second script like this:

```cs
    public GameObject object1;
    int level;

    void Update()
    {
         level = object1.GetComponent<name_of_script>().Level;
    }
```

**Important:** put this name of the first script (the one you are accessing) in the <> where it says `name_of_script`. I think I saw your class name, so this is what it would be in your situation (if I saw right):

```cs
    public GameObject object1;
    int level;

    void Update()
    {
         level = object1.GetComponent<Box>().Level;
    }
```

If you have both scripts on the same object, just remove the object1 variable like this:

```cs
    int level;

    void Update()
    {
         level = GetComponent<name_of_script>().Level;
    }
```